# Weekly date range in between years in php

Tags: php

can you help me on how to get the weekly range  in between years.

For example:

Date Selected: Dec 16 , 2014 to Jan 15,2015

Weekly Range Should be:

Dec 16, 2014 to Dec 21,2014 
Dec 22, 2014 to Dec 28,2014 
Dec 29, 2014 to Jan 4, 2015 
Jan 5, 2015 to Jan 11,2015 
Jan 12, 2015 to Jan 15, 2015

There is a similar solution

[Get all week start date and end date within a date range in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684700/get-all-week-start-date-and-end-date-within-a-date-range-in-php)

But this doesn't work in between years, it gives incorrect weekly range.

Answer (score 1):

try using this code

```
$p = new DatePeriod(
            new DateTime('2014-16-12'), 
            new DateInterval('P1W'), 
            new DateTime('2015-15-01')
            );
        $dates=array();
        foreach ($p as $w) {
            $date_week= $w->format('Y-m-d');
            $date_week_7= strtotime($date_week);
            $dates[] =date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+7 day",  $date_week_7));

        }
```

$dates array will contain all the week days between the dates

Comment: It seems its PHP 5. Is there other way around not use PHP 5

Comment: Oh how can i make it run to my computer. Will i need to re install my Xampp?

Comment: yes update your php version here is the link http://www.techflirt.com/how-to-upgrade-php-in-xampp/

Comment: Is there any other way to do this not in PHP 5

Comment: i am not very much familiar with lowest versions .try to update your wamp or lamp whatever you are using.

Comment: Hi John, the code above doesn't satisfy  my questions.

Comment: it will work only in the php version greater than  5

Comment: array (size=5)
  0 => string '2014-12-23' (length=10)
  1 => string '2014-12-30' (length=10)
  2 => string '2015-01-06' (length=10)
  3 => string '2015-01-13' (length=10)
  4 => string '2015-01-20' (length=10) , The output is like this its not in range like on requirements above